# How can I disable hover effect on image link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover

Can anyone please work out why the background colour for my text-links appear on my image-links despite my every effort to disable it?

I made a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25wqoxn0/)

```
<div class="pink">
  <p>
   The <a href="#" target="blank">link</a>
  </p>
  <a class="imagelink nohover" href="#" target="_blank">
   <img src="http://www.royalcanin.ca/~/media/Royal-Canin-Canada/Product-Categories/cat-adult-landing-hero.ashx" alt="image" style="max-width:476px;max-  height:275px;border:0;">
  </a> 
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}

.pink a {
  color: white;
}

.pink img a:hover  {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.imagelink:not(.nohover):hover{
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.pink a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that the `.pink a:hover` applies to all links in your div container, if you set a CSS class specifically to your link you want to style your problem is solved

**HMTL**

```
The <a href="http://www.onthehouse.com.au/" target="blank" class="style-only-this">link</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.pink .style-only-this:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/25wqoxn0/1/

Comment: It works! Thank you, I wish I had asked a few hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the css hover written for image,

```
.imagelink:not(.nohover):hover{
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

New:

```
.imagelink.nohover:hover{
  background: transparent;
}
```

Check the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25wqoxn0/2/)